# How to click the back navigation button of the browser using helium?

Tags: automation, helium

I am trying to implement helium in my project. I checked the API doc of helium but I didn't find any command to click the back navigation button of the browser.

In the API doc found solution to launch the browser. Code is as following

```
startFirefox();
startFirefox("google.com");
```

So I would appreciate if any one can help me with this. Is it possible to integrate selenium and helium all together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I don't  find any way to implement click back navigation of the browser using only helium, So I integrated selenium along with helium

```
getDriver().navigate().back();
```

It worked for me

Comment: Is it working? I think it should be getDriver().navigate().back(). getDriver() is Helium's method which returns the Selenium WebDriver currently used by Helium to execute all commands.

Comment: 'd' will be uppercase in getDriver() actually. I have corrected it

Answer (score 0):

Even Don't find any way to navigate back using helium

```
getDriver.navigate().back();
```

Worked for me!!!

Comment: How have you created the instance of driver?

Comment: How is it working? You should use getDriver() method of helium to get the driver instance.

Comment: yes it's true we need to use getDriver.navigate.back();